# Facebook: is it possible to post to profile page via api

Tags: wordpress, facebook, api

I'm helping a friend setting up a WordPress blog. I wanted to add the possibility to push a post from wordpress to his facebook profile.

I know I can do that if I setup a developers app, but I'd like to keep it simple by just posting to the friend's profile. is it possible?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a simple share post button, then this should do it:

```
<a class="post_share_facebook" href="<?php echo esc_url('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='.get_permalink()); ?>"><i class="icon-facebook"></i></a>
```

Of course you'll need a proper icon name that he has from his icon font.

Comment: No, what I meant is to automatically post from wordpress to facebook.

Comment: Oh, automatically. Did you search any plugins for that? Because I don't think that's a trivial thing.